# Convert XLS to CSV using PHPEXCEL lib but without transferring the blank rows into the CSV file

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel, xls

The following code converts every sheet of an XLS file to a CSV file. But I cannot find a way to stop it from including the blank rows from the XLS into the CSV.

Please help me.

```
   function convertXLStoCSV($infile, $outfile) // the function that converts the file
{
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $writer->setDelimiter(",");
    $writer->setEnclosure("");
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $workSheetIndex => $worksheet) 
    {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($workSheetIndex);
        $writer->setSheetIndex($workSheetIndex);
        $writer->save('converted/' . $outfile ."_" . $worksheet->getTitle() . ".csv");


        echo $outfile;
        echo $infile;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to loop through each row, testing if it is blank, and delete it if it is, before saving

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I am trying very hard to get this to work but just can't.